# Session not persist when request comes from android device

Tags: android, laravel, session, persistence

I have created an REST API for mobile application for both IOS/Android.
I was trying to create a signup/login system in which user logs in with his mobile number so while signup I have to verify his/her number. So when a user proceed to signup and fill his/her information, mobile developer sends the user information to API i.e,(name, country, city, language, phone_number). On the backend I store all the information in a session and send a verification code on user's mobile number, verification code also stored in a session. When user enters his mobile number mobile app again send arequest with only one parameter i.e, (verification_code). I match the user sent code with the code that is in the session if it matches then get all the data from session and create a new user with that information..

The PROBLEM is when ios developer send request, I can get his session data while when android developer sends request his session is always empty..

I have also tested API on postman and there is no single issue, issue is only when request comes from android device. Is the android device do not do management for sessions ?

I am developing API in laravel 5.2,

Please help me to resolve the issue!
Sorry for my bad english as its not my native language..

Comment: Please include code in your question so you will receive better aimed answers.

Comment: were u able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my case: I experienced this session losing problem and I found it out that the `dd(...)` is the problem. If you just dumping the variable with v`ar_dump(...)` everything's fine. Normally `$_SESSION` won't lost its content if I run `die(...)`. Why Laravel needs to run $app->terminate() or `$kernel->terminate()` to persist session every single request?

As I noticed `Auth::user()` is persisted across requests.

**In-short don't use dd() or exit() in your code**